# What can cause a client.Call rpc to return an error in Go (golang)?

Tags: go, rpc

When does `c.Call(...)` return a non-nil value?

Can the `c.Call(...)` only return an error when a network failure occurs (packets lost or timed out or something along those lines)?

If the server `srv` crashes, will `c.Call(...)` return an error?

Specifically, can `c.Call(...)` return an error AFTER the request successfully arrived at `srv` but BEFORE the `rpcname` handler function returns?

```
import (
    "net/rpc"
    "fmt"
)

func call(srv string, rpcname string, args interface{}, reply interface{}) bool {
    c, errx := rpc.Dial("unix", srv)
    if errx != nil {
        return false
    }
    defer c.Close()

    err := c.Call(rpcname, args, reply)
    if err == nil {
        return true
    }

    fmt.Println(err)
    return false
}
```

Comment: TFM says: `Call invokes the named function, waits for it to complete, and returns its error status.`

That's not specific as to what happens beyond that. What would probably happen if the acknowledgement of execution fails to reach the client because of a network error, is an error or even a panic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a look at [`client.go` in the source code for `net/rpc`](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/rpc/client.go) you'll see quite a few lines where `call.Error` is set. These should show you all of the conditions under which a `Call` will return an error.

Many of them are generated upon encountering errors from `ClientCodec.WriteRequest` and `ClientCodec.ReadResponseBody`. See the [`ClientCodec` docs](http://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/#ClientCodec) for more details.

There are also a couple of possible errors for encountering unexpected EOF, and `ErrShutdown` when the client is closing.